# Named conditions in Python and a silly textbook - and how to prove they're wrong

Tags: python, macros, boolean-logic, abstraction

Python's abstraction is often seen as magic by many. Coming from a C background, I know very well there is no such thing as magic, only cold hard code made up of simple components that produces abstraction.

So, when a textbook and my teacher say that we can "store conditions" or use "named conditions" for readability, and say that assigning a boolean expression to a variable suddenly makes it a dynamic condition akin to a macro, I lose it.

---

**EDIT 1** : They don't explicitly say its like a macro (direct quotes are placed within quotes) since we aren't expected to know any other language beforehand.

*The way they say* that " the variable stores the condition unevaluated ", is *like* saying it is a macro , and this is my opinion. They imply it to be practically the equivalent of a macro by their articulation, just without saying the word 'macro'.

---

Here's the claim in code form :

```py
x,y = 1,2
less = x < y 
more = x > y

'''
less/ more claimed to store not boolean True/False but some magical way of storing the
expression itself (unevaluated, say like a macro) and apparently 
'no value is being stored to less and more'. 
'''
```

It is being represented as though one was doing :

```c
// C-style
#define less (x < y) 
#define more (x > y)
```

Of course, this is not true, because all `less` and `more` store in the so-called 'named conditions' is just the return value of the operator between `x` and `y` .

This is obvious since `<` , `>`, `==` , `<=` , `>=` all have boolean return values as per the formal man pages and the spec, and `less` or `more` are only storing the `True` or `False` boolean return value , which we may prove by calling `print()` on them and/or by calling `type()` on them.

Also, changing the values of x and y , say by doing `x,y = y,x` does not change the values of `less` or `more` because they store not a dynamic expression but the static return value of the `>` or `<` operand on the initial `x` and `y` values.

The question isn't that this claim is a misunderstanding of the purported abstraction ( its not actually an abstraction, similar storage can be achieved  in asm or C too) , but rather **how to clearly and efficiently articulate** to my teacher that it is not working like a C macro but rather storing the boolean return value of `>`or `<` statically.

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think this is a question, or at least not a SO question. You already presented a couple of methods to prove your point (swapping the x, y or using print/type on less/more). And you can use those to correct your teacher

Comment: Equally respectfully: I think it might be a good idea to stop taking this course if its instructor doesn't know the fundamentals of the language they are teaching.

Comment: Is that a direct quote? Then it is plainly wrong. `x < y` is an expression, a boolean expression involving a comparison operator. It gets evaluated eagerly, and the result of that expression is assigned to the name `less`. This is basic, standard Python, I'm not sure if we can really tell you any way to convince some unknown person.

Comment: @Amir I was also getting my own stance peer-review and backed up to be correct. I must verify what I am saying regardless of how true I think it is, so in a way if I was so sure of something wrong, SO would have come down heavily on me and I would have know ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith refer my comment to Frank Yellin's answer here : Its a school , and I don't have much say. On the bright side, I already know more Python the course attempts to teach

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga as shocking as it is to you, it is even more to me :) Yes, everything within quotes is a direct quote from the class. Your right, because I though the exact same things , and am finding it equally confounding .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously `less = x < y` just looks at the current values of `x` and `y` and stores either `True` or `False` into the variable `less`.

If I understand where you and your teacher disagree, you two have a different idea of what the following code will print out:

```
x, y = 1, 2
less = x < y
print(less)
x, y = 2, 1
print(less)
```

Comment: That you have a textbook that says that `less` is a macro is really bad.  To have a teacher who doesn't know any better is far, far worse.  Is there anyway you can find a different textbook and a different teacher?

Comment: Frank : Doesn't say so but implies it. As for changing stuff - yes and no. Yes because I already know this stuff very solidly and have taught myself long before this course so I am not exactly learning from this. No because this is high school and there is a fixed teacher and textbook that the school decides for us \\_0_0_/ . The teacher comes from C++ , I come from C. To be honest, the national curriculum and the government's textbook have no such discrepancies but for some odd reason the school has prescribed a 'guidebook' as our textbook , saying it was allegedly 'better' - all plain bs XD

Comment: @user13863346 to be fair, this textbook may have been foisted on your teacher, and they may not know Python. It isn't *crazy* to think there would be some behavior like this, certain languages already do things kind of like this this when they support call by name, thunks, etc.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, my teacher's passion does lie in C++, like mine does in C :) . Of course it isn't crazy, at the simplest level we have macros that do exactly this. But the only way I see a true macro-like 'placeholder for this/these line(s) of code' feature is just functions in python.

Comment: @FrankYellin these four line of code will solve my conundrum of articulating my point to my teacher. I'll simply ask her what she think this will result in (just in an `if less:` form , since that is where she brought up this idea of 'named conditions' ) and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

"Macro's" could be implemented as text strings that can be evaluated, like (bad example - not the recommended solution):

```py
less = "({0}) < ({1})"
```

and use them like:

```py
x = 1
y = 3
outcome = eval(less.format("x", "y"))
```

But this is really a silly thing to do, and `eval()` is susceptible for security issues.

Perhaps your teacher meant to use [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), which are nameless, ad-hoc functions:

```py
less = lambda a, b: a < b
x = 1
y = 3
outcome = less(x, y)
```

**Note:**
There is already a function for `lambda a, b: a < b` available in the [standard library operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html): `operator.lt`.

Comment: Neither my teacher nor me know enough Python to know what your talking about :(